# Sample Implementation of Binary Trees doesn't work for large number of values

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I have recently trying to implement a binary tree, it seems to work for less than 1000 values, but after that eventually it gives me stack overflow error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;
struct Node{
    long long int val;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};
struct BinaryTree{
    Node *head  = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    bool headSet = false;
    Node* findLast(Node *asgn,int val){
        if (val > asgn->val){
            if (asgn->right != NULL)
                asgn  = findLast(asgn->right, val);
            else
                return asgn;
        }
        else{
            if (asgn->left != NULL)
                asgn = findLast(asgn->left, val);
            else
                return asgn;
        }
        return asgn;
    }
    void insert(long long int vals){
        if (headSet){
            Node *asgn = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
            asgn = findLast(head,vals);
            Node *fix = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            fix->val = vals;
            fix->left = NULL;
            fix->right = NULL;
            if (vals > asgn->val){
                asgn->right = fix;
                asgn->left = NULL;
            }
            else{
                asgn->right = NULL;
                asgn->left = fix;
            }
        }
        else{
            head->val = vals;
            head->right = NULL;
            head->left = NULL;
            headSet = true;
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    BinaryTree a;
    for (long long int i = 0; i < 100;i++)
    a.insert(i);

    return 0;
}
```

For example:-
If i change

```
for (long long int i = 0; i < 100;i++)
    a.insert(i);
```

to

```
for (long long int i = 0; i < 10000;i++)
    a.insert(i);
```

It gives me error. I can't seem to understand why this is happening, where the stack overflows?

Comment: @Treycos What can i do to minimize it?

Comment: @Treycos What is porg?

Comment: You are allocating memory for asgn, and then overwriting the pointer with the return value of findLast(). This causing a memory leak (but it's not the cause of the stack overflow)

Comment: The problem is a combination of two things: use of recursion, and the degenerate (linear) nature of the binary tree you are generating.

Comment: Idk why people vote down questions like this.  They are the very essence of a coding learning experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stack overflow comes from your `findLast` method, once the binary tree becomes too big the recursion becomes too much and overflows the call stack at one point. You should convert it into a non-recursive method by storing information about the search in some kind of structure and dynamically allocating that so that your stack doesn't fill up.

P.S use `new` instead of `malloc` in C++ and `delete` to clear up allocated memory, you're currently leaking memory.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me, i will try to correct it.

Comment: @Hudixt `findLast` can easily be written iteratively, not need for recursion at all here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  I am not able to think of any way to do it without recursion. I tried to look it on net, and i found many of them are using recursion.

Comment: @Hudixt a piece of paper and a pencil may help here.

Comment: btw:  `Node *asgn = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));` in `findLast` is useless. If you don't find out why, ask here.

Comment: btw: the `insert` algorithm is wrong anyway. Try to insert sucessively 4, 1 and 5 into the tree and inspect the tree then.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It looks like inserting 4, 1, and 5 would set `head->val = 4`, `head->left->val = 1`, and `head->right->val = 5`, which looks correct unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @IanAbbott see my answer below.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Oh I see. I never spotted the other branch pointer being reassigned to `NULL`!

Comment: @IanAbbott nor did the OP. It looked as if it worked, because the left pointer was never assigned in his program due to the inserted values be strictly increasing.

Answer (score 2):

Iterative version:

```
Node* findLast(Node *asgn,int val){
  while (1)
  {
    if (val > asgn->val) {
      if (asgn->right != NULL)
        asgn = asgn->right;
      else
        return asgn;
    }
    else {
      if (asgn->left != NULL)
        asgn = asgn->left;
      else
        return asgn;
    }
  }
}
```

Easy, isn't it ?

And the corrected version of `insert`:

```
void insert(long long int vals){
   if (headSet){
       // Node *asgn = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));   // removed
       Node *asgn = findLast(head,vals);               // line changed slighty
       Node *fix = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
       fix->val = vals;
       fix->left = NULL;
       fix->right = NULL;

       if (vals > asgn->val){
           asgn->right = fix;
            //asgn->left = NULL;     // removed
       }
       else{
           //asgn->right = NULL;     // removed
           asgn->left = fix;
        }
    }
    else{
        head->val = vals;
        head->right = NULL;
        head->left = NULL;
        headSet = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..... I finally figured it out... It's way more faster than using stupid recursion

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer as such. I just want to suggest a code change as an addendum to the original code with Michael Walz's corrections. My suggestion is to omit the `headSet` member and initialize the `head` member to `NULL`, and allocate `head` on first insert, like this:

```
struct BinaryTree{
    Node *head  = (Node *)NULL;
    Node* findLast(Node *asgn,int val){ // Courtesy of Michael Walz
        while (1){
            if (val > asgn->val){
               if (asgn->right != NULL)
                   asgn = asgn->right;
               else
                   return asgn;
            }
            else{
                if (asgn->left != NULL)
                    asgn = asgn->left;
                else
                    return asgn;
            }
        }
    }
    void insert(long long int vals){
        Node *fix = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        fix->val = vals;
        fix->left = NULL;
        fix->right = NULL;
        if (head != NULL){
            Node *asgn = findLast(head,vals);
            if (vals > asgn->val){
                asgn->right = fix;
            }
            else{
                asgn->left = fix;
            }
        }
        else{
            head = fix;
        }
    }
}
```